# Copy only value of one object to another not property javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var defaults = {
CrfFlag: null,
Table: null,
Config: { DS: null, UserID: null, Password: null }
}

var opts = {
CrfFlag: "temp",
Table: "t1",
foo: "Foo"
}
```

I want result as below: I dont want foo in my result object

```
var result = {
CrfFlag: "temp",
Table: "t1",
Config: { DS: null, UserID: null, Password: null }
}
```

I just tried below code ($.extend) but it does not satisfy my requirement

```
var result = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);
<br/>
result = {
CrfFlag: "temp",
Table: "t1",
foo: "Foo",
CABIDBConfig: { DS: null, UserID: null, Password: null }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `for..in` and iterate on default and check if they exists in opts then overright otherwise move on. !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var defaults = {
CrfFlag: null,
Table: null,
Config: { DS: null, UserID: null, Password: null }
}

var opts = {
CrfFlag: "temp",
Table: "t1",
foo: "Foo"
}
var result = {
CrfFlag: "temp",
Table: "t1",
Config: { DS: null, UserID: null, Password: null }
}
this is right way of overiding in which it override behaviour